# foreach connection foreach and select SUM

Tags: php, function, foreach, codeigniter-3, public

How can I join a foreach with another foreach in the query WHERE.
I have stored in the second Foreach the contents with the ID of the first ID and wants to display this in the respective column.
So if in the second column db_buy.tb_buy_shop has the ID 2, this should show in the HTML column where the db_shop.tb_shop_id 2.

view:

```
<?php
    foreach ($shops_where_1 as $shop_where_1):
        foreach ($buy_sums as $buy_sum):
            if($buy_sum['tb_buy_shop']==$shop_where_1['tb_shop_id']) {
                $gesamtsumme = $buy_sum['gesamtsumme'];
            }
        endforeach;
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $shop_where_1['tb_shop_name']; ?></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon">€</div><input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo number_format($buy_sum['gesamtsumme'],2,",",".");?>" disabled></div></td>
            <td><div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon">€</div><input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo number_format($gesamtsumme,2,",",".");?>" disabled></div></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
<?php
        // endforeach;
    endforeach;
?>
```

Model:

```
public function shops_where_1()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('db_shop');
    $this->db->where('db_shop.tb_shop_buy = 1');
    $this->db->order_by('tb_shop_name');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}

public function buy_sums()
{
    $this->db->select('(SELECT SUM(db_buy.tb_buy_gesamt) FROM db_buy) AS gesamtsumme');
    $this->db->select('(SELECT SUM(db_buy.tb_buy_abbezahlt) FROM db_buy) AS abbezahlt', FALSE);
    $this->db->select('tb_buy_shop');
    $this->db->from('db_buy');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Controller:

```
public function buy_shop($slug)
{
    // if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
        // {
            // redirect('users/login');
        // }
    $data['get_shops'] = $this->Admin_model->get_shops($slug);
    $data['shops_where_1'] = $this->Admin_model->shops_where_1();
    $this->load->view('templates/header_acp');
    $this->load->view('admin/buy_shop', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

[image: Excpected]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I recommend that you read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can get the help you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am correct in what you are asking it seems that you are just wanting to know how to format the code so that it will build the table. This would be how to do so.

```
<?php
foreach ($shops_where_1 as $shop_where_1):
 ?> <tr>
    <td><?php echo $shop_where_1['tb_shop_name']; ?></td>
<?php
    foreach ($buy_sums as $buy_sum):
        if($buy_sum['tb_buy_shop']==$shop_where_1['tb_shop_id']) {
          ?>
        <td><div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon">€</div><input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo number_format($buy_sum['gesamtsumme'],2,",",".");?>" readonly></div></td>
<?php
        }
    endforeach; // endforeach 2
    </tr>
endforeach; // endforeach 1;
?>
```